# How to access data from query inside component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I need to access `{ excerpt, title, author, category, slug, readTime, image }` those data from the query, I have tried many time, but I can't think how to do.

my code is:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

const SEO = () => {
  return <div>SEO Component</div>
}

export const query = graphql`
  {
    allMdx(limit: 3, sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }) {
      nodes {
        excerpt
        frontmatter {
          title
          author
          category
          date(formatString: "MMMM, Do YYYY")
          slug
          readTime
          image {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData
            }
          }
        }
        id
      }
    }
  }
`

export default SEO
```

after that I want like this

```
const SEO = ({ excerpt, title, author, category, slug, readTime, image }) => {
  return <div>SEO Component</div>
}
```

Then I will access those data inside my `SEO` component.

I'm new in graphQL

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you should query that data in your template. Take a look at https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/blob/master/src/templates/blog-post.js

Comment: @ksav, thanks, but I need direct data like this: `const SEO = ({ excerpt, title, author, category, slug, readTime, image }) => {
  return <div>SEO Component</div>
}`

Comment: Query the data in your template, and pass it as props to the `SEO` component.

Comment: @ksav, please if can write in the answer section, then it will really help for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queried data is inside `props.data`, destructured as `{ data }`. [Page queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/), the one you are showing in your `SEO` component are only available in the top-level components (pages).

The idea when dealing with this kind of component is to move the query for each page you want and drill down the data to the `SEO` component through `props`. For example:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

 const HomePage = ({data}) => {
  console.log("your queried data is", data);

  return (
    <div>
      This is your home page
    </div>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  {
    allMdx(limit: 3, sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }) {
      nodes {
        excerpt
        frontmatter {
          title
          author
          category
          date(formatString: "MMMM, Do YYYY")
          slug
          readTime
          image {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData
            }
          }
        }
        id
      }
    }
  }
`

export default HomePage
```

In the example above, `allMdx` data is inside `props.data.allMdx`. At this point, you can do something like:

```
 const HomePage = ({data}) => {
  console.log("your queried data is", data);

  return (
    <div>
    <SEO {...data.allMdx.nodes[0].frontmatter} excerpt={data.allMdx.nodes[0].excerpt}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Note that the spread operator (`...`) will allow you to pass the list of props under `frontmatter` object, there you only need to get them by destructuring `props` in the SEO component like:

```
const SEO = ({ excerpt, title, author, category, slug, readTime, image }) => {}
```

Since the `excerpt` is in another level than the rest of the `frontmatter`, you can pass it isolated as another `props` or you may want to create a new object mixing all properties of the current `allMdx` data and pass the whole object using the spread operator but the approach of the snippet above will work for your use-case. Tweak it as you wish.